# Launch screen doesn't display the logo image

Tags: ios, xcode, nslayoutconstraint, launch-screen

In my launchscreen storyboard, I have 2 image views, one for the background and the other for the logo.

It was working fine until I just changed the image of the logo!

I will get only the background!!!

Here a screenshot of the storyboard:

[image]

and here a screenshot of what I get:

[image]

I double checked the constraints and everything is fine and set properly.
I just changed the logo image and everything messed up.

How to solve this and whats wrong?!

Comment: you must check constrain what you given for that imageView

Comment: is that image is included in target?

Comment: Clean the build, Restart the simulator and Xcode worked for me.

Comment: @NitinGohel i did and its set properly!

Comment: @NaumanMalik yes it is

Comment: try opening debug view hierarchy and check is there any uiimage on your screen.

Comment: @ImadAli same :(

Comment: @V.Khambir i got: unable to capture view hierarchy

Comment: @mrs.tat Did you delete the previous app and clean the build folder in Xcode (Press alt and product in the Xcode menu).

Comment: @ImadAli just did.. and same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device cache the old launch screen and doesn't show your new images, just try to restart the device then reinstall, it will show your new images